# Responsiveness- How to control PC display's scale and layout with CSS?

Tags: css, web, responsive-design

so far when I have been trying to create responsive websites I have always used media queries to control the screen resolutions. However, while most PC screens have 100% on their scale, many laptops are 125% or even 150%. Is there any way to add CSS attributes designated only to those with a 150% scale display?

Answer (score 2):

There is no option for Controlling zoom level in a browser by a code, But mobile devices can restrict the zoom options by using below meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You could probably do that with some JS but it will probably be a ton of custom edge case coding. Another approach would be utilizing `viewport` units. That way you can ensure all your users will get the same experience no matter how big or small there resolutions are.

Checkout this codepen example and resize the screen/ change the display to see what I mean

https://codepen.io/oneezy/pen/oJYoEG

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; font-family: "Roboto"; }

/* Styles
***************************/
header { background: black; color: white; display: flex; align-items: center; }
p { opacity: .78; }




/*==============================================                                           
  ####    #####  ##   ##  ##   ####  #####  
  ##  ##  ##     ##   ##  ##  ##     ##     
  ##  ##  #####  ##   ##  ##  ##     #####  
  ##  ##  ##      ## ##   ##  ##     ##     
  ####    #####    ###    ##   ####  #####  
==============================================*/

/* Mobile */
@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 768px) { 

 h1 { font-size: 9vw; padding: 2vh 0; }
 h2 { font-size: 7vw; }
 p  { font-size: 4vw; }
}
  
/* Tablet */
@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px) { 

 h1 { font-size: 7vw; padding: 2vh 0; }
 h2 { font-size: 5vw; }
 p  { font-size: 3vw; }
}
  
/* Desktop */
@media (min-width: 1025px) { 

 h1 { font-size: 6vw; padding: 2vh 0; }
 h2 { font-size: 4vw; }
 p  { font-size: 2vw; }
}
```

```html
<header>
 <h1>Heading</h1>
</header>

<main>
 <article>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p>I'm a paragraph. I'm a paragraph. I'm a paragraph. I'm a paragraph. I'm a paragraph. I'm a paragraph. I'm a paragraph. </p>
 </article>
 
 <article>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p>I'm a paragraph. I'm a paragraph. I'm a paragraph. I'm a paragraph. I'm a paragraph. I'm a paragraph. I'm a paragraph. </p>
 </article>
 
 <article>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p>I'm a paragraph. I'm a paragraph. I'm a paragraph. I'm a paragraph. I'm a paragraph. I'm a paragraph. I'm a paragraph. </p>
 </article>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this meta.

```
<!–– 150% scale -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.5"/>
```